# MongoDB GridFS using C# driver - Is there a way to Update or Append chunks directly?

Tags: c#, mongodb, driver, gridfs

I want to do web upload a very lage file say >10GB file to MongoDB GridFs.

I know that Gridfs chunks the data and keeps the files in two collections, named by default fs.files and fs.chunks, but for this I believe I need to pass the whole file and GridFS will do its own chunking and saving metadata internally.

Here is my approach,

- I am splitting the file from client side using javascript.
- Sending the chunks of the file with orderId to C# web API, which might not be received at server side in order.
- Store the chunks in GridFS as separate files in a temporary bucket (Since I donot want to store the files in file system)
- Read the chunks from GridFS temporary bucket using orderId and merge the file.
- Store it in GridFS actual bucket and delete the temporary GridFS bucket and its contents.

My question is, is there any option to Append/Update the chunks directly? Can I avoid creating temporary bucket and edit the metadata and chunks? Is there any way that I upload the chunks directly which I recieve from client and update the metadata of both fs.chunks and fs.files and done with upload.

I want to avoid the memory usage when I am merging the file. Any quick help would be much appreaciated.

Comment: Could you not simply have your endpoint part collect the "splits" and then write to the same "stream"? The [driver lets you do that](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/gridfs/uploadingfiles/#uploading-from-a-stream), so presumably as long each split is written to the stream in sequence, then the original order of the file is maintained. If you were thinking along the "append" line then you should have figured out the sequencing already. But "stream" would seem the logical choice.

Comment: Agreed With Neil, Streaming in packets is reliable option for such huge data.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, I need to use OpenUploadStream to open the stream and start writing the chunks to it, if recieved in order. On Close, the stream upload to gridfs will be complete. I had tried UploadFromStreamAsync, but not this. I will try this. Thanks a lot for quick help.

Comment: One more question, How can I use the same bucket to store different chunks of files? I don't see any option to get the same bucket by name.